# How to find out Azure KeyVault AccessPolicy Changes

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-rest-api

I have a requirement to Audit all changes in **AccessPolicies** of **Azure KeyVaults**. I see that there is some event getting written in **ActivityLog** of the AKV. But I only see who has initiated the change (Caller) But Activity does not tell me what level of access has been provided to AKV.

Comment: hello @Vinny , have you referred this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/how-to/get-resource-changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to view what level of access has been provided/removed from your AKV, you can select the `Operation name from your Activity Logs -> Change History -> Select properties.accessPolicies` - [AKV Activity Log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxubG.png).

Once on the "Changed Properties" screen you can select your desired property to see the old value and new value correlating to a ObjectID (user, group, service principle). [Old Value/New Value screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acT2r.png)]